# Why does Azure Load Balancer not work for machines not in an availability set?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-load-balancer

I created 2 VMs in the same availability set, and added them to a basic load balancer, and that worked fine.

Then I tried to do the same thing, the only two differences being that the VMs were not in an availability set, and I used a standard load balancer instead of basic.

One difference I noticed is that a standard load balancer will allow you to add VMs to the backend pool even though they are not in an availability set.

However I found that I could not connect to the machines through the load balancer's public IP address. Instead I get a connection timeout error. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely correct.

Basic SKU Load Balancer supports Virtual machines in a single availability set or virtual machine scale set as a Backend pool endpoints

Standard SKU Load Balancer supports Any virtual machines or virtual machine scale sets in a single virtual network as a Backend pool endpoints

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/skus

To have possibility to connect to Virtual machine via load balancer's public IP you have to configure port forwarding in Load Balancer.

- Create an NSG rule for the VM, allow connection on RDP 3389 port
- Create a health probe on Load Balancer
- Create a load balancer rule
- Create an inbound NAT port-forwarding rule

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/tutorial-load-balancer-port-forwarding-portal

Comment: For the answer to the "why" should be reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46418623/1176573).